# OpenGL 3 on Galaxy S4 Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I am new to Android development so I may be missing something. My understanding is that a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.4.2 should support OpenGL ES 3. However, when I call `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` (after getting an OpenGL ES 2.0 context) I get `OpenGL ES 2.0 build 1.10@235947.` I would expect to get an `OpenGL ES 3.0` string if it was supported.

If I try to force getting a OpenGL ES 3.0 context my render thread is given an exception and the Log message is `throwEglException tid=1477 createContext failed:` .

The really odd thing is that if I use a 2.0 context, openGL ES 3.0 calls work fine (like Array Buffers), I just get Log messages that the call is `not implemented.` !!??

My `AndroidManifest.xml` has:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />
```

Is there something I'm not setting to get me OpenGL 3.0? Does Android 4.4.2 on a Galaxy S4 (Verizon BTW) not really support OpenGL ES 3?

Here is my renderer setup in my GLSurfaceView constructor:

```
public BasicGLSurfaceview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    MyRenderer renderer = new MyRenderer(context);
    setRenderer(renderer);
    ...
```

If I pass a 3 to setEGLContextClientVersion() instead of 2, my render thread is given a 'createContext failed:' exception. I have also created my own context factory and used setEGLContextFactory(), but the results are the same. Asking for a version greater than 2 results in my render thread getting an exception.

Comment: Have you tried NDK gles3jni sample? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/ndk/platforms/android-18/samples/gles3jni/

Comment: Can you show the code where you create your context? If you use `GLSurfaceView`, that would be the code where you set up your `Renderer`, probably in the `GLSurfaceView` constructor.

Comment: I have tried the NDK gles3jni. It just stops.

Comment: Here is my renderer setup code from my GLSurfaceView:   public BasicGLSurfaceview(Context context) {
       super(context);
       setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
      MyRenderer renderer = new MyRenderer(context);
//    setEGLContextFactory(new MyGLSurfaceView.DefaultContextFactory());
      setRenderer(renderer);

Comment: Looks to me like your device does not support ES 3.0 with the Android build you have.

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung Galaxy S4 shipped with two different CPUs, depending on the country.  The GT-I9505 version, which has a Snapdragon CPU, supports OpenGL ES 3 under Android version 4.3 or later, but the GT-I9500, which has an Exynos CPU does not.

See: [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES)
See: [SAMMOBILE Article](http://www.sammobile.com/2013/03/20/your-country-will-get-exynos-or-snapdragon-variant-of-the-galaxy-s-4-we-have-the-answer/)